# Rails 3 nested form - New object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, simple-form

I can't remember on the code, how to create new object in nested form (via Simple-form).. It was something like: "something :new_object ..."

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dropbox, I found it..

You need add this to your javascript (in CoffeScript)

```
#= require jquery_nested_form
```

And that's the form (in HAML)

```
= simple_nested_form_for @variable do |f|
  = f.input :code
  // Link to create new empty object    
  = f.simple_fields_for :nested_attributes do |s|
    = f.link_to_add "Add new", :nested_attributes
    = s.input :name
    = s.input :locale
    // Link to remove
    = s.link_to_remove 'Remove'
  = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Normallyc use:

```
<%= f.fields_for :object do |builder| %>
```

But you can use **simple_fields_for**, like this:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.simple_fields_for :posts do |posts_form|
    # Here you have all simple_form methods available
    posts_form.input :title
  end
end
```

Reference: http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br/#usage/extra-helpers

It is initially using **form_for**, but check this thread: [nested attributes in simple_form returns mass assignment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892159/nested-attributes-in-simple-form-returns-mass-assignment-error)

Comment: I have this, but I need to create new empty :post. I had button "Create new empty post for user". Something like link_to :new_object, but I forgot how exactly is it